# elasticsearch handling typos

Tags: elasticsearch

is it possible elasticsearch to handle **queries containing typos**.
Example

```
trying to query "colthes" would return results of "clothes"
```

If that's possible, how to do it ? (which **analyzer**? which **tokenizer**? which **filter**?)

Could you show an example? Is it possible to apply the configuration for non-english languages (i'm looking for french)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is certainly possible. A working example for french can be seen [on this site](http://med-code.info/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=abbendice&catalog=icd&country=ch&locale=fr), which uses Elasticsearch as a back-end. For example by searching for "abbendice" the query returns "appendice" (appendix in english). Specifically what you're looking for is the [fuzzy query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/fuzzy-query.html).

Be aware though that it may not be suitable depending on the size of data you're trying to index. Hope that helps.